# functional components to import a collection of functions?

Tags: reactjs

So, a functional component in react, as I have been using them, is like an imported component that return something like so:

```
const example = () => {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Example;
```

What I want to know, is can i use the for just functions? As an example:

```
const Example = () => {
    function exampleFunction(){
        const first = 1;
        const second = 2;
        console.log('first:', first);
        console.log('second:', second);
    }
}

export default Example;
```

Then import it or something like that? As in, can I use a functional component just for functions, without returning HTML or JSX?

Comment: No, but you can use a… function? `export default function exampleFunction() { … }`

Comment: Then just import the function and use it wherever?

Comment: Then just import the function and use it wherever, yes.

Comment: It seems hooks arent working inside of it. is there something i need to do to make that work?

Comment: I wouldn’t know, because you didn’t include any details. That’s what the question is for. See [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. For example:

```
const Example = () => {
    const first = 1;
    console.log('first:', first);
}

export default Example;
```

The above example would print to console 'first: 1' on every render. You can use hooks as usual inside the component. If you do not want your function to be executed on every render you can [wrap it in a useEffect with an empty dependency array](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects#what-an-effect-with-empty-dependencies-means), or [wrap `Example` in `memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo).

I can imagine this being used to perform some computation and log its result.  I believe there are less surprising ways to do the same (for example with `useEffect`), but if this works for you, I would at least recommend to explictly return `null` from the component so the intent is clearer.

Here's a complete example:

```js
// Our logging component
const LogUserId = React.memo(({ id }) => {
  console.log("User ID: ", id);

  return null;
});

// Some UI component where the data we are interested in is not displayed
const ProfilePage = ({ user }) => {
  return (<div>
    <h1>{user.name}</h1>
    <p>Age: {user.age}</p>
    <LogUserId id={user.id} />
  </div>);
};

// Our example data
const user = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 22,
  id: 42,
};

//Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<ProfilePage user={user} />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```